# $.ajax().promise, what does it return?

Tags: jquery, ajax, promise, rxjs

I am going through rxJs, auto-complete [example](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/examples/autocomplete/autocomplete.js#L13). The argument function to `flatMapLatest` returns a `$.ajax().promise`. what does it mean?

I have come across code that uses `$.ajax.done, then, fail`. But what does promise function return?

The code block is,

```
$.ajax({
      url: 'http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php',
      dataType: 'jsonp',
      data: {
        action: 'opensearch',
        format: 'json',
        search: global.encodeURI(term)
      }
    }).promise()
```

Comment: Your first stop: [**The documentation**](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).

Comment: Side note: There's absolutely no point whatsoever to that `.promise()`. You can simply delete it, for two reasons: 1. You're not using the return value for anything (`.then`, etc.), and 2. Even if you were, those are already on the jqXHR object `ajax` returns anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One usual goal of using `.promise()` method is to prevent resolving the Deferred object by the clients (callers) of some methods: one cannot control the state of Promise.

In this case, however, the purpose is unclear at best: `jqXHR` object cannot be successfully resolved (it can be aborted, however, so it's not strictly a `Promise`). Still, in your example the result isn't even used or returned.

Comment: yup, the functionality remains intact after removing `.promise`.. thanks all

Answer (score 1):

The jqXHR objects returned by $.ajax()  implement the Promise interface, giving them all the properties, methods, and behavior of a Promise . These methods take one or more function arguments that are called when the $.ajax() request terminates. This allows you to assign multiple callbacks on a single request, and even to assign callbacks after the request may have completed.

http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/